# Backslash escaping in RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: asp.net, regex, reg-expressionvalidator

I need to ensure that the input value contains at least one dot, so I have used the following:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="MyInput" Text="*" 
ErrorMessage="must contain at least one dot" 
ValidationExpression="\.+" />
```

And that doesn't work. By inspecting the page source i can see that ASP.NET escapes the backslash character so in java-script it looks like `"\\.+"`. Why does it do so and how do i prevent RegularExpressionValidator from escaping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the input contains at least one dot, your expression is incorrect. It matches only input that consist only of dots.

You should use

```
.*\..*
```

If escaping proves to be a problem, too, use `[.]` instead of `\.`.

Note that the RegularExpressionValidator does not validate empty fields. Use the RequiredFieldValidator to do this.

Comment: Are you sure that the `RegularExpressionValidator` implicitly searches for start and end of string? AFAIK it does *not*, hence `\.` should be a sufficient pattern.

Comment: I just tested it. It does. At least the one I use here on my webiste.

Comment: Thanks! That means that default JS regexp options are different from .NET Regex class, because the latter works fine. That is strange - if we have JS disabled RegularExpressionValidator should use server-side check (i.e. Regex class), shouldn't it?

Comment: I stand corrected, then. But why on earth is the control implemented in that way? (Rethorical question, I do not expect you to know the answer.)

Comment: @Jørn: I guess the control if designed to check things like zip codes, credit card numbers and such. You'd need an exact match more often.

Answer (score 1):

The double escape is necessary because the backslash is used for escape sequences in both JavaScript and regular expressions. A quick test to illustrate this point:

```
alert('42'.match("\d"));     // no match
alert('42'.match("\\d"));    // match
```

But that does not solve your problem. First step in troubeshooting: change the validation expression to `a`. Does it not fail on "foo" and pass on "bar"? If not, something else is wrong on your page - possibly an unrelated JavaScript bug causes the validation code to be skipped.

Slightly off topic: Your validation expressions can be trimmed to `\.` (without the plus), as you really only care about matching a single dot.

Comment: A single backslash works as well:
`alert('12.3'.match("\."));`

Comment: @frogbot: You are right. I have updated with a better sample.